# wiringpi2 digitalWrite() has no effect

Tags: gpio, pi-2, output, wiringpi

Hello fellow rpi lovers :-)

I've encountered a very strange problem in my rpi-based project:

I'm trying to control just one pin in `OUTPUT` mode so I use more or less such code:

```
import wiringpi2
wiringpi2.wiringPiSetupGpio()
wiringpi2.pinMode(26, wiringpi2.GPIO.OUTPUT)
wiringpi2.digitalWrite(26, wiringpi2.GPIO.HIGH)
```

The problem is that the pin changes its state after `pinMode` command and then it does not react to any `digitalWrite` execution.

The only way to change the pin state is to use `pinMode` with `OUTPUT`/`INPUT` parameter.

Anyone has idea what can be wrong?

Update:

`gpio readall` output:

```
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 2---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 |   IN | 1 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5V      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 |   IN | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |   IN | 1 |  7 || 8  | 1 | ALT0 | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 1 | ALT0 | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |  OUT | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |   IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI |   IN | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO |   IN | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK |   IN | 0 | 23 || 24 | 1 | IN   | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 1 | IN   | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |   IN | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | IN   | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |   IN | 1 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |   IN | 1 | 31 || 32 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |   IN | 0 | 35 || 36 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |   IN | 1 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 2---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Are you trying to use physical pin #37 as an output ? Most probably you would be looking at the wrong pin number. As far as I know, `SetupGpio()` accepts BCM pin numbering. Make sure you're measuring the correct pin. Diagram here : (for reference) http://data.designspark.info/uploads/images/53bc258dc6c0425cb44870b50ab30621 The number beside GPIO is bcm number. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried various ports with the same result. The numbering is correct - otherwise the `pinMode` would not affect the state of the pin.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include `gpio readall` snapshot on terminal ?

Comment: Presumably something is connected to 26 (whatever 26 may mean).  That must be forcing 26 high or low.

Comment: This pin is connected to input port of relay board so I doubt its state is somehow forced

Comment: Which pin do you mean?  BCM 26 or wPi 26?

Comment: Physical pin 37 / BCM 26

Comment: Are you sure this is the snapshot after executing the code you mentioned above ? Best way to check if it's working or not by using plain `gpio` command on terminal. Use `gpio mode 25 out` to set gpio in output mode, use `gpio write 25 0` to make it low and `gpio write 25 1` to make it high, 25 because 25 is equivalent Wpi number. If it doesn't work, like joan mentioned, it could be something external making gpio to go high or low. Hope it helps.

Comment: I run `watch gpio readall` in one console, and `bpython` in another and tried several settings ... and results are as follows:

   * according to `gpio` the `digitalWrite` command changes the state of the pin
   * notwithstanding the pin state, the relay stays on when connected to the pin
   * relay is on when connected to GND, off when connected to +5V.

Comment: So the GPIO is switching between 0 and 3V3.  Presumably 3V3 is not enough to switch the relay.  Does the relay operate when you connect IN to pin 1 (3V3)?

Comment: @joan that might be it!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that @joan was right.

The state of the pin is changed correctly but the relay-board treats `3.3V` as a `LOW` state thus not react.

Thank you for valuable tips :-)